# not sure if MIDI controller is sending MIDI data to Ubuntu or not

Tags: audio, alsa, midi

I'm trying to use a hardware keyboard (the Arturia KeyStep Pro) as a MIDI controller via USB in my digital audio workstation (Bitwig) under Ubuntu 22.04. So far, it's not working, and I'm not certain it's sending MIDI data at all.

`lsusb` recognizes the device:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c75:0218 Arturia KeyStep Pro
```

`amidi -l` recognizes it as an ALSA device:

```
IO  hw:2,0,0  KeyStep Pro MIDI 1
```

`arecordmidi -l` gives the output:

```
 Port    Client name                      Port name
 14:0    Midi Through                     Midi Through Port-0
 24:0    KeyStep Pro                      KeyStep Pro MIDI 1
```

I've gotten a bit confused between JACK, ALSA, and the rest of the acronyms and utilities whose functions I only half-understand. Can anybody help (1) verify that the device is in fact sending MIDI via USB, and (2) help me get Bitwig to recognize the MIDI notes the device is sending?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to shut down JACK for a while (or disable its MIDI processing by using the driver `none`) and connect ALSA MIDI output port that corresponds to your keyboard to QMidiRoute input see if there are any messages coming from it. It will decode and display which kind is a message, MIDI channel and other information. (Use QJackCtl, it can control ALSA MIDI connections despite the name.)

If Bitwig is able to work with ALSA MIDI, you can leave JACK in this state at all and just connect via ALSA in the same way.

If it requires JACK MIDI, the best is still not to use jackd builtin drivers, but use [a2jmidid](https://github.com/jackaudio/a2jmidid) to present ALSA MIDI ports as JACK MIDI ports, which you then can connect with QJackCtl whichever way you want. I only use static bridges, but you may find the daemon useful.

Answer (score 0):

Run `amidi -p hw:2 --dump` or `aseqdump -p 24:0`.

In Bitwig, MIDI input devices can be configured in Settings / Controllers.